# Query on array property or embedded property

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j

consider following classes:

```
class Basic{
    String id;
    Double val;
    //some other member variables
}

class NodeBO{
    List<String> id;
    Type type;
    // list of id from objects of Basic class in data below

    Map<ChEnum, Basic> data;

    addBeans(NodeBO nodeBO, Node node){
        // in transaction...
        node.setProperty("priperties", nodeBO.toString());
        // is it ok to convert to array? or should be converted to JSON string?
        node.setProperty(GraphElementProps.id,toArray(nodeBO.id));
        node.setProperty(GraphElementProps.type, nodeBO.type);
    }

    @override
    toString(){
        //return json of this object
    }

}

enum ChEnum{
    CH1(1), CH2(2);
    // constructor and some methods
}
```

nodes are indexed using autoIndexer:

```
AutoIndexer<Node> nodeAutoIndexer = GRAPH_DB.index().getNodeAutoIndexer();
nodeAutoIndexer.startAutoIndexingProperty(GraphElementProps.id);
nodeAutoIndexer.setEnabled(true);
GRAPH_NODE_AUTO_INDEX = nodeAutoIndexer.getAutoIndex();
```

Here I'm storing `GraphElementProps.id` as node property (by converting to array). Does it take array (of string) as property? Or should I convert list to JSON-string and then store?

I want to be able to query on this array given with `queryId`. e.g. query on node-index to get nodes in which `node.getProperty(GraphElementProps.id)` contain given `queryId`? i.e. something like:

```
// how to do this?
GRAPH_NODE_AUTO_INDEX.get(/*Nodes whose id contain queryId*/);
```

Or is it (somehow) possible to make `id` property of `Basic` class indexable and searchable? How to index such properties, if possible? and how to query them?

I'm unable to understand but is it something related to `Spring-data-neo4j`? I'm completely new to `Spring-data-neo4j`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use [Spring-data-neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/spring). This will allow to index embedded fields and query on them.